# How can I prevent Entity Framework from mapping a class into a database table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created a viewmodel which kind of has a reference to an entity type.

Here's my viewmodel:

```
namespace SuperMart.Areas.Admin.ViewModels
{
    [NotMapped]
    public class ProductDetailVM
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Price")]
        public double Price { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Sub Category")]
        public string SubCat { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Category")]
        public string Category { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Status")]
        public bool Available { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date Created")]
        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ProductImages> ProductImages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

An entity type referenced by the viewmodel:

```
namespace SuperMart.Entities
{
    public class ProductImages
    {
        [Key]
        public int ImageID { get; set; }

        public byte[] ImageContent { get; set; }
        public string ImageContentType { get; set; }
        public string ImageName { get; set; }
        public FileType FileType { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Product")]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }

        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I marked the class with a `[NotMapped]` attribute to say I don't want it to be a database table since it is only a view model and not an entity type. However EF is still attempting to create this as a table when I run add-migration command which then causes a foreign key conflict. I tried the `modelBuilder.Ignore` too but one way or the other EF seems to be ignoring that code as it is still creating the class as a table as shown below.

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
                "dbo.ProductDetailVMs",
                c => new
                    {
                        ProductID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        ProductName = c.String(),
                        Price = c.Double(nullable: false),
                        Description = c.String(),
                        SubCat = c.String(),
                        Category = c.String(),
                        Available = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        DateCreated = c.DateTime(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.ProductID);

            AddForeignKey("dbo.ProductImages", "ProductID", "dbo.ProductDetailVMs", "ProductID", cascadeDelete: true);
        }
```

Comment: Please show us the ViewModel class in question.

Comment: @Serv I've updated the question with my code

Comment: Which entities does your `DbContext` contain? Normally, to map an entity you need to include a `DbSet<Entity>` property in the `DbContext`.

Comment: I've only seen `[NotMapped]` on attributes. But I can't find reliable documentation stating this is the only valid usage.

Comment: To answer my own comment: [NotMappedAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.notmappedattribute(v=vs.103).aspx) `Denotes that a property or class should be excluded from database mapping`.

Comment: Ok, turns out i kinda shot myself in the leg. I found out that that class was present in my DbContext class hence the problem with the mapping. but i must confess i seriously do not know how it got to be there. Anyways problem solved.

Comment: Please post your last comment as self-answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, to map an entity you need to include a DbSet property in the DbContext. –  Martin Liversage

Ok, turns out i kinda shot myself in the leg. I found out that that class was present in my DbContext class hence the problem with the mapping. but i must confess i seriously do not know how it got to be there. Anyways problem solved.

Comment: Happened to me too. I right clicked ActionResult to add a View and chose a template, that auto added relevant class to DbContext.